# Apache Drill Kudu query doesn't support range + hash multilevel partition

Tags: apache-drill, apache-kudu

[Drill Kudu query doesn't support range + hash multilevel partition](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL/issues/DRILL-7044?filter=allopenissues).

Kudu table :

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int ,
    name string,
    value string,
    prmary key(id, name)
),
PARTITION BY HASH (name) PARTITIONS 8,
PARTITION BY RANGE (id) (
    PARTITION 0 <= VALUES < 10000,
    PARTITION 10000 <= VALUES < 20000,
    PARTITION 20000 <= VALUES < 30000,
    PARTITION 30000 <= VALUES < 40000
);
```

and then insert 20002 rows into test1, but query not support.
  query sql : select count(1) kudu.table_name, result : **No result found.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [drill issues 7044](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL/issues/DRILL-7044?filter=allopenissues)

Comment: Looks like it is not implemented in Drill yet.
Besides that Kudu storage plugin is not actively used by Drill users. Drill even doesn't have a good documentation for this plugin.
So contributions for this plugin are very welcome.